# Possible faucet leaking only when the valve is turned off

Tags: faucet, valve, washing-machine, hose, leaking

I have a problem about my washing machine faucet that is strange for me. When I use my washing machine, there is no problem.

A few days ago, I was not at home for 3-4 days and I iust turned off the main valve at my apartment. However, when I came back, I saw that there was a lot of water on the ground in my bathroom. Although the main valve was turned off, the washing machine caused the leaking. I can understand based on the movement of the water on the ground since the ground is not completely flat. I saw some water drops between the hose and the faucet.  However, the strange thing for me is that in the normal time there is no problem. Besides, I waited half an hour without turning on the main valve to watch what is going on. But except a few water drops between faucet and hose, nothing happened. I have two points that I did not get.

1. How could the water leaking happen when the main valve is turned off.
2. Considering the a few water drops, it is impossible to have that much water on the ground in 3-4 days.

What do you recommend? Should I turn off the valve again and investigate more?

BTW, this happened last year when I again turned off the valve but there was not too much water. So I did not take it serious. Then I traveled two times after that, did the same things, nothing happened (not even a drop). However, this time it happened again and there was too much water compared to last time.

Thank you and best.

[image: Picture of the faucet]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the leak was from the tap rather than the roof?

Comment: Even with the water off the system is still charged and can leak water.

Comment: I included another photo and marked the area. I only saw a water drop there when the valve is turned off. Other parts were dry.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably there's a leak developing in the valve stem packing, and that leak is closed off when the valve is open.

So the packing needs to be replaced. Some people will replace the whole valve, but that's generally not required and involves extra expense.

The valve handle should be removable. Looks like there might be a blue screw in the center of it, and then the handle itself will pull off, typically, revealing a nut (the packing nut) around the valve stem (the part the handle turns.)

You MAY be able to resolve the leak by very slightly tightening that nut. That will compress the packing a bit more, and the tightness of it is a balance between "not leaking" and "making the valve too hard to operate." If that does not solve the problem, you'll need to replace the packing.

With the water shut off upstream of this valve (possibly requiring turning off the water to the whole house depending on how the valves are arranged in your system) you would unscrew that nut to access the valve stem packing, which is usually a rope-like teflon product these days, and can be gotten from a plumbing or hardware store. The new packing is wound tightly into place and then compressed by reinstalling the packing nut.